# How do I hide axes in a plot of means?

Tags: r, plot, axes

I want to omit the x-axis labels for my plot of means, but I just fail (I didn't use packages such as ggplot2):

```
with(richness_formok,plotMeans(barklicerare,invstatus,error.bars="conf.int", level=0.95, xlab="", ylab="", main="")) # normal code
with(richness_formok,plotMeans(barklicerare,invstatus,error.bars="conf.int", level=0.95, xlab="", ylab="", main="",frame=F))   # which gives no response
with(richness_formok,plotMeans(barklicerare,invstatus,error.bars="conf.int", level=0.95, xlab="", ylab="", main="",axes=F))
```

This gives the following error:

> Error in plot.default(c(1, n.levs), yrange, type = "n", xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab,  : 
>     formal argument "axes" matched by multiple actual arguments

Comment: Oh yes I have also use xaxt(), but also no response

Comment: Try this: in the plot statement use `axes = F` then add a `axis` statement if you want axes on the left or right sides.

Answer (score 0):

The below code temporarily sets the color of axis tick labels (i.e., for both the x and y-axis) to "transparent" using `par`, thus preventing the automatically drawn tick labels from being visible. The y-axis tick labels can easily be inserted afterwards by reverting the `par`-related modifications.

```
## sample data
library(Rcmdr)
data(Moore)

## create plot with transparent (i.e., non-visible) tick labels
par(col.axis = "transparent")
with(Moore, plotMeans(conformity, fcategory, partner.status, 
                      ylim = c(0, 25)))

## add y-axis tick labels
par(col.axis = "black")
axis(side = 2, at = seq(0, 25, 5), tick = FALSE)
```

[image: plotMeans]

Remember that this is a rather undesired behavior of `plotMeans` since the help pages explicitly say that `...` are arguments to be passed on to `plot`. Therefore, if your target is to entirely disable the drawing of the frame and axes when using `plotMeans`, e.g. similar to the visual output of `plot(1:10, 1:10, axes = FALSE)`, you should probably file a bug report.

---

**Update**

In case I understood it wrongly and you actually wanted to remove both the tick labels and the ticks, you could simply use

```
par(xaxt = "n")
with(Moore, plotMeans(conformity, fcategory, partner.status, 
                      ylim = c(0, 25)))
```

[image: plotMeans__no_xaxis]

See also `?par` for further possible modifications of R base plots.

Comment: I can use the par(xaxt="n") to hide the x axis, but I fail to create a transparent axis

Comment: That's what suggesting to issue a bug report was for. Obviously, disabling the axes via `axes = FALSE` needs to be enabled by the package developers first.

Comment: @Fay, then why not just create the plot and run `axis(1, at = 0:10, col = "white", labels = FALSE)` to color the plot frame and tick marks in white as long as this hasn't been dealt with in the package?